# Remove \r\n\r\n from csv File

Tags: python-3.x, replace, logfile

My LogFile looks like this because I accidentally added a string that consists of `\r\n\r\n` to the log script (Arduino Upload to ThingSpeak):

```
created_at,entry_id,field1,field2
"2017-09-10 09:21:43 UTC,18,23.10,""48.70"

"
2017-09-10 10:20:35 UTC,19,23.10,48.30"

"
```

it should look like this:

```
created_at,entry_id,field1,field2
2017-09-10 09:21:43 UTC,18,23.10,48.70
2017-09-10 10:20:35 UTC,19,23.10,48.30
```

So all the Blank lines and the `"`s in the LogFile should be removed.
What's the best way in python 3.x to convert the LogFile. I tried a few approaches with the csv reader in python e.g looking for `\r\n\r\n` or `\"`in the rows and replace them but it did not work.
My main problem is to define  what I am looking for that needs to get replaced. In my understanding that should be every `"`and every blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the csv module's `DictReader` accepts any object that supports the iterator protocol (more or less). This means that we can read your log file in a function that returns lines from it, suitably modified as necessary, using `yield` statements.

In this function I return the first line unchanged except for stripping it of it end-line character(s). When I encounter a line containing a UTC I discard the double-quotation mark characters and strip the end-lines. Other lines are ignored altogether.

```
>>> def csvfile():
...     with open('logfile.txt') as logfile:
...         first = True
...         for line in logfile.readlines():
...             if first:
...                 first = False
...                 yield line.strip()
...             else:
...                 if 'UTC' in line:
...                     yield line.replace('"', '').strip()
...                 else:
...                     continue
...
```

This bit of code shows what `csvfile` accomplishes.

```
>>> for thing in csvfile():
...     thing
... 
'created_at,entry_id,field1,field2'
'2017-09-10 09:21:43 UTC,18,23.10,48.70'
'2017-09-10 10:20:35 UTC,19,23.10,48.30'
```

Now we can put it to use. The function takes the place of a file.

```
>>> import csv

>>> reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile())
>>> for row in reader:
...     row
...     
{'created_at': '2017-09-10 09:21:43 UTC', 'field1': '23.10', 'entry_id': '18', 'field2': '48.70'}
{'created_at': '2017-09-10 10:20:35 UTC', 'field1': '23.10', 'entry_id': '19', 'field2': '48.30'}
```

You most likely want to add some code to decode the date, etc.